# spawnSync error and can\'t find loc string warning with ContainerStructureTest@0 task of azure-pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

After building a docker image, I am trying to test its functionality using [ContainerStructureTest@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/container-structure-test-task?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) from azure-devops.

I have a [pipeline](https://github.com/tashrifbillah/docker-azure/blob/d5ce4893a2ac550d9a16c530c8fb5008760cd9f2/azure-pipelines.yml) and test [configFile](https://github.com/tashrifbillah/docker-azure/blob/d5ce4893a2ac550d9a16c530c8fb5008760cd9f2/structure-test.yaml).

Firstly, it gives the following warning:

```
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: FoundDockerConfigStoredInTempPath
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: OldDockerConfigContent
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: AddingNewAuthToExistingConfig
```

Then, yields the following error:

```
[command]/home/vsts/work/_tasks/ContainerStructureTest_39bc2c9b-55b7-4835-89cd-6cc699ef7220/0.1.2/container-structure-test test --image ***/entry_point:latest --config /home/vsts/work/1/structure-test.yaml --json
##[error]Error in executing the command: Error: spawnSync /home/vsts/work/_tasks/ContainerStructureTest_39bc2c9b-55b7-4835-89cd-6cc699ef7220/0.1.2/container-structure-test ETXTBSY
##[error]Error: Error in executing the command: Error: spawnSync /home/vsts/work/_tasks/ContainerStructureTest_39bc2c9b-55b7-4835-89cd-6cc699ef7220/0.1.2/container-structure-test ETXTBSY
```

I do confirm that my configFile is copied into the virtual machine:

`/home/vsts/work/1/structure-test.yaml`

Since your documentation is not complete yet, I followed the syntax from https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test

I have a feeling that this task is not configured properly. Can anyone help me solve the error?

Comment: I am facing the same execute error with you even test with the File test script or just print out "hello world" with command test. Since there has result displayed in the doc, the function should completed. I think this issue should relevant with our test scrip. I am achieving the correct test from our internal way. Will share it with you once I got any feedback from that team.

Comment: Thanks @MerlinLiang-MSFT. I appreciate it.